# Setting hostname for new AWS EMR worker nodes

Tags: amazon-emr

Just getting my feet wet with setting up a Spark cluster using AWS EMR. Is it possible to set the hostnames on the nodes that gets created? Right now they have names in the form of `ip-172-29-10-22.MYDOMAIN`. The problem we're having is we can't resolve said hostnames because we're using our own BIND server. It would be ideal if I could set the hostname to a dynamic value and then update Route53.

I suppose I could use the bootstrap action but wouldnt that run every time the workers run a job? It would be idempotent in this case but is there a more valid approach?

Comment: I don't think this is a good practice instead you should configure the custom dns to forward dns queries to vpc dns reaolver .2